# Probablity distribution for two particles to decay?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, mathematical-physics

Let us say I have the probability distribution of the decay of one particle as:
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{\tau}e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$$ 
Then how would I find the probablity distribution for the time it takes two (specific) particles to decay (given that they have the same probablity distribution as given above, and that the decay of one particle is independent of that of the other)?

Comment: What exactly is meant by $P(t)$? A probability density function, I guess. The notation is confusing because letter P makes one think that $P(t)$ denotes a probability. Also independency should be mentioned.

Comment: @drhab I have edited my question according to your suggestions. (and yes I did mean a probablity density function :) )

Comment: Are you familiar with [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)? If the decays of particles start at the same time (do they?) then you are actually looking for the distribution of $\max(X_1,X_2)$ where the $X_i$ are iid and have exponential distribution.

Comment: @drhab yes I am familiar with this distribution and I agree  that I am after $max(X_1,X_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T_i$ denotes the decay of particle $i$ then we can find the CDF of $M:=\max(T_1,T_2)$ by: $$P(M\leq t)=P(T_1\leq t\wedge T_2\leq t)=P(T_1\leq t)P(T_2\leq t)=(1-e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}})^2$$

The PDF of $M$ can be found by differentiating the CDF.